# In foreach maping ids

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach, adonis.js

I have company product packages.
I need to get current company product packages. Am trying to get than like this

```
  const packageIds = user.company.products.forEach(async (prod) => {
      await prod.load('packages')
      const pckgIds = prod.packages.map((packg) => packg.id)
      // i can get ids in here
      console.log(pckgIds)
    })
    // here i get undefined, how can i get here package Ids?
    console.log(packageIds)
```

I don't understand why I get undefined in packageIds

Comment: you cant await in a forEach

Comment: I need await to load prod.load('packages') and the function must not be async where can I do async to load packages?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: my function must not be async

Comment: You got `paclageIds` undefined, because the `forEach()` returns undefined. If you need a value, you should use `map()` or `reduce()` if products is an array. If it is not, you need to initialize  `paclageIds` and update it in the forEach body.

Comment: first i used map but it's returning   Promise {
    <pending>, }

Comment: ...but just keep in mind, the `packageIds` you will get is **not complete**, because of the `async` stuff.

Comment: So `map()` is fine, just return the prod.load(), and you should then pass to `Promise.all()` and pass a callback to the `.then()`. That because you cannot make the current function async.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I never used Promise.all() really don't know how to do it all. Please if u have time and u give me an example of how can solve this problem. am trying to do this for like 4 hours...

Comment: I used promises like this:    packageIds = user.company.products.map(async (prod) => {
      await prod.load('packages')
      await Promise.all(prod.packages).then((value) => value.map((p) => p.id))
    }) but packageIds  returns Promise {
    <pending>,

Comment: Promise must be await function so how can it work? o O